# Databricks ADSL Mount with Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to access the ADSL file from databricks.
I tried using SAS Token, Access key and Also with SPark.config (Service Principle) But its still not working.

```
storageAccountName = "adlskush"
storageAccountAccessKey = "AccountKye"
sasToken = "SASToken"
blobContainerName = "input"
mountPoint = "/mnt/data/"
if not any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
  try:
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = "wasbs://{}@{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(blobContainerName, storageAccountName),
      mount_point = mountPoint,
      #extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': storageAccountAccessKey}
      extra_configs = {'fs.azure.sas.' + blobContainerName + '.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': sasToken}
    )
    print("mount succeeded!")
  except Exception as e:
    print("mount exception", e)
else:
    print('not run')
```

[image]

I have given access to the storage account

[image]

here is mount code which is not showing me data from container.
[image]

Please someone please help me with.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your selected virtual network and IP address?

Comment: Due to a security issue, i cant provide it. But let's say i have not created Correctly VNAT then please guide me